# combining object names with numbers

Tags: c#, syntax

please consider that this is my first very post and that I´m a newcomer in C#

I'm creating a UserControl with several pictureBoxes. These objects are automatically named pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3 and so on.

Now i want to change the associated image by clicking:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.i51;
```

so far, so good. But how to assigne the number without writing a single line for each event?

```
pictureBox(1).Image = Properties.Resources.i51;
```

doesn´t work, and lots of others don´t too.

any hint? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill all your picture boxes into a list like msmolka already provided and also add a ReadyOnlyCollection to it:

```
private List<PictureBox> _PictureBoxes;
private ReadOnlyCollection<PictureBox> _PictureBoxesReadOnly;
```

Instantiate it within the constructor:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     _PictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
     _PictureBoxesReadOnly = _PictureBoxes.AsReadOnly();
}
```

And make the ReadOnlyCollection only available as `IList`:

```
public IList<PictureBox> PictureBoxes
{
    get { return _PictureBoxesReadOnly; }
}
```

This is (in my eyes) better than the approach from msmolka. For making it perfect i would also not give the whole PictureBoxes to the outer world, but instead only the `Image`s as a `BindingList`. But i think for a beginner you can start with the above and maybe improve this stuff later.

Comment: If you would extend it to a `BindingList<Image>` this would be only internally. To the outer world it would stay as an `IList<Image>`, but now people could add, remove, etc. the list and you could react on these events to manage your picture boxes at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can create list of picture boxes on your user control:

```
List<PictureBox> boxes = new List<PictureBox>();
```

Now after picture boxes initializes in constructor add them to list:

```
boxes.Add(pictureBox1);
boxes.Add(pictureBox2);
...
```

Now make it visible byu public property:

```
public List<PictureBox> Boxes
{
    get 
    {
       return this.boxes;
    }
}
```

Now you can assign in your class by:

```
Boxes[0].Image = Properties.Resources.i51;
Boxes[1].Image = Properties.Resources.i51;
```

If all is happeining in the same class, you don't need to create above public property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) for things like that, for *example*:

```
int iControlNum = 1;
PictureBox pb = this.FindControl("pictureBox" + iControlNum.ToString())
                as PictureBox;
pb.Image = ...;
```